# How to fetch SQLite data from selected Spinner item in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have retrieved all the first column data in `Spinner`. I want to retrieve SQLite data when I select a spinner item. The data will be displayed in `EditText`s. But when I run the app, data cannot be displayed in the `EditText`. Can someone give me a suggestion?Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
spinner_searchByEmpName = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.searchByEmpName);
        loadSerachBYProject() ;


spinner_searchByEmpName = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.searchByEmpName);
        loadSerachBYProject() ;

        spinner_searchByEmpName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectedEmployeeName = spinner_searchByEmpName.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                System.out.println("selectedProjectName " + selectedEmployeeName);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



            etEmpName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Delete_editText_StaffEmployee_Name);
          etDepartment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Delete_editText_Department);
          etDesignation=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Delete_editText_Designation);

        try {


            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT staff_emp_name, department, designation FROM employee_details WHERE staff_emp_name = ?",
                            new String[] { "" + selectedEmployeeName });

            if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            {

                  etEmpName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("staff_emp_name")));



                    etDepartment.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("department")));

                    etDesignation.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("designation")));  
                }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: What happens while running this code?

Comment: @Gunaseelan: While i run it is not showing any error and not showing any row data in edit_text's.

Comment: okay, now print `cursor.getCount()` and tell me the answer.

Comment: @Gunaseelan: It shows cursor size is 0.

Comment: @Gunaseelan :  why not display my row data in Activity. Where is the problem.

Comment: Because that query did not retrieve any data, That is why it shows cursor size is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at tutorial in android database here take a look: [Android SQLite database and content provider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Never use a hardcode name for your table name and columns store them in variables like this one:

```
public static final String EMP_TABLE = "employee_details";
public static final String EMP_COL_NAME = "staff_emp_name"
```

You can create an object representing your data in your database like this one:

```
public class Employee{
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String designation;

    public Employee(String name,String dept,String designation){
        this.name = name;
        this.department = dept;
        this.designation = designation;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Also refactor your method like the one below:

```
  private Employee getEmployeeByProj(String name){
 try {


            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();


             final String where = EMP_TABLE + "=\"" + name + "\"";

            Cursor cursor = db.query("employee_details",new String[] {"staff_emp_name","department","designation"},where,null,null,null,null);

            if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            {

                        final String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(EMP_COL_NAME));
                        final String dept = cursor.getString(....
                        final String designation cursor.getString(.....

                      //do the rest of the code here

                  return new Employee(name,dept,designation);
                }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

I suggest you take a look on the link i given you above

Comment: Still not display the data.

Comment: Make sure you have data first, try it in terminal using sqlite or you can download a sqlite browser for mozilla firefox

Comment: the problem must be in your query @Robotics

Comment: Thanks allot million, my code is working , you are great !! Thanks once again.